# How to fill ranges of filler bytes inside structs

Tags: c++, struct, byte, c++20

What is the best way to fill areas within a struct with multiple consecutive filler bytes?

Inside a header I have the following struct:

```cpp
struct MY_STRUCT {
    uint8_t importantUint8_t1;
    uint8_t importantUint8_t2;
    uint8_t importantUint8_t3;
    uint8_t filler[4];
    uint8_t importantUint8_t4;
    double x0;
    double y0;
}
```

At a later time I would like to fill this struct. At the moment I don't understand how I can fill the four filler position at once. Currently I have the following solution that works, but I would like to improve it if possible.

```
unsigned char important1[1] = {0};
unsigned char important2[1] = {0};
unsigned char important3[1] = {0};
unsigned char important4[1] = {0};
unsigned char filler[1] = {0};
double x0 = 20.0f;
double y0 = 12.0f;

MY_STRUCT results{
    * important1, 
    * important2,
    * important3,                
    * filler,
    * filler,
    * filler,
    * filler,
    * important4,
    x0,
    y0,
}
```

Is this best practice? Or is there an obvious better way of doing this job.

Comment: Use [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers) to initialize only the `x0` and `y0` members? Then the rest will be default (zero) initialized.

Comment: Thank you. This works and cleans the code a lot. Fell free to provide an answer, so that I can accept it.